# JDEdwards EnterpriseOne 9.2 Debugging jdeObjectCall

Tags: jde, enterpriseone

I have a UBE that is failing after making a call to a jdeObjectCall. The API returns a 1, indicating a warning, which indicates to the report to stop processing.

The image below shows the jdeObjectCall in question that is returning a 1.

[image: jdeObjectCall Example]

I'd like to determine why jdeObjectCall is returning a warning, so that I can investigate a fix.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Cheers, Cam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to determine the answer to this question with some help from the forum jdelist.com.  The topic in which I discovered my answer can be found here: https://www.jdelist.com/vb4/showthread.php/53758-E1920-Debugging-jdeObjectCall

The way I found my solution is as follows.  Apologies for the high-level steps.  There is some assumed knowledge here.  If you are interested in a more in-depth explanation of one of these items please comment and I will provide it.

1. Enable logging in the jde.ini file.
2. Debug the locally.
3. Examine the output of the log file using a tool like JDETrace.
4. You can do a search for your business function within JDETrace.  In my case, I searched for EditDate.
5. The line in the log will let you know the name of the busines function object.
6. Checkout the object in object management workbench.
7. Find the line where the EditDate function exists.
8. Place a breakpoint on this line and continue debugging.